# "this" keyword don't work as expected in mongoose update method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to access the "this" keyword inside a validate method. When validation occurs when I call a create, it happens as expected, but when it comes to an update, I can't access the model's attributes with this.

**Validator method in Box Schema (products attribute):**

```
{
    // check stock quantity
    validator: async function (products) {
        const productIds = products.map(product => product.product);

        for (const pId of productIds) {
            const product = await Product.findById(pId);

            const matchingProduct = products.find(p => p.product.toString() === product._id.toString());

            if (matchingProduct.quantity * this.stockQuantity > product.stockQuantity)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    },
    message: `One or more products do not have this quantity available in stock`
}
```

**Box controller method (line for update):**

```
const updatedBox = await Box.findByIdAndUpdate(productId, req.body, { runValidators: true, new: true });
```

The intention is to run the validations in the update as well. What I want is to be able to access stockQuantity, an attribute present in the Box model, to access it in the validation operation. this.stockQuantity works fine when dealing with a create, but returns undefined when dealing with an update.

**I've already tried a few things but I couldn't, not sure due to a syntax error or what.**

Comment: What exactly do you expect `this` to be? There is no object instance in the code you're showing, `validator` is a property of a plain, unclassed, unprototyped object, so `this` is going to be whatever scope the function runs in, when it runs.

Comment: You cannot rely on `this` unless you know exactly the context under which this function is executed. I would suggest using a higher level/global variable instead of `this` pointing to the model you need.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans My question is why 'this' refers to the object when it comes to create but not when it comes to update. Shouldn't the scope in which the validation is performed be the same in both functions?

Comment: @RAllen stockQuantity is an attribute of the model where the validation function is located. I need this value from the document being created or updated to perform this validation correctly. How could I do that, in that case? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @LuizCarlosGandra to be able to help you I need more context. I've tried to google for `Box Schema` but cannot find anything. Is "Box" a framework? How do you define a model? Can you share more of the related code? As an option, try `console.log(this)` to see what `this` points to and what you can access from there. Maybe you can access the model from `this` through some property of `this`.

Comment: @LuizCarlosGandra `this` is a placeholder for "whatever the scoping rules say the current execution context is", so it literally depends on how you call your function, so remember to show that as [mcve]. There are loads of different things `this` can point to depending not just on the code you wrote but also the way the _rest_ of your code invokes it.